# me aparece este error al intentar iniciar pyttsx3

Tags: python

me aparece esto al pone "pip install pyttsx3":
que puedo hacer

> ```
> > ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> > 'C:\Users\sergi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'
> > -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\sergi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b8cg91k3\\comtypes\\setup.py'"'"';
> > __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sergi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b8cg91k3\\comtypes\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> > '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> > '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> > install --record
> > 'C:\Users\sergi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-gdub1bn7\install-record.txt'
> > --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\sergi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Include\comtypes' Check the logs for full command output.
> ```

Comment: Pues si no sé si te has equivocado al escribir, pero el comando es "pip install" no "pip instalar"

Comment: Como dicen en el comentario anterior deberías instalarlo con ``pip install pyttsx3`` , una vez que ejecutes el comando, puedes comprobar su instalación con``pip list``

Comment: Lo he provado y no funciona igualmente

Answer (score 0):

Primero desinstala esa version:

```
pip uninstall pyttsx3
```

Luego instala:

```
pip install pyttsx3==2.71
```